# MapAt and generic Functions on Associations and Datasets

Tags: functional-style, dataset, associations

These are distinct but related questions about mapping functions to Associations and Datasets. Given:

```
assoc = <| a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3|>
```

And

```
data = 
 Dataset@{<| a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3|> , <|a -> 4, b -> 5, c -> 6|>}
```

Re MapAt:

```
MapAt[Framed, Key[b]][assoc]
```

[image]

Although Dataset is not explicitly mentioned in the doc page for [MapAt](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html?q=MapAt&lang=en), it's supposed to apply to generic expressions. However:

```
MapAt[Framed, Key[b]][data]
```

[image]

Next, consider mapping over a named `Key` with this syntax:

```
data[All, {Key[b] -> Framed}] // Normal
```

[image]

Why don't the following variations work on `Dataset`?

```
data[All, Key[b] -> Framed] // Normal
```

[image]

```
data[All, Key[b] -> Framed[#] &] // Normal
```

[image]

Finally, back to Association:

```
assoc[Key[b] -> Framed] // Normal
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That `MapAt[Framed, Key[b]][data]` doesn't work is a bug, which I'll fix (thanks!).

On the other hand, `data[All, Key[b] -> Framed]` is not a supported syntax for doing applying a function to a specific part. You *have* to have the enclosing list.

As for `data[All, Key[b] -> Framed[#] &]`, the second query element there is a pure function. Pure functions get applied to the corresponding part of the Dataset, so the behavior you see is absolutely correct (and of course, useless).

In `assoc[Key[b] -> Framed]`, you're doing a key-lookup on an association via function application. In particular you're looking up the key `Key[b] -> Framed`, which doesn't exist in the association. Hence you get Missing.

Comment: Re "the second query element there is a pure function", how can generic functions with multiple arguments be passed, eg StringDrop[#,-1]&? - Of course can pass a predefined curried version but that's lame.

Comment: @alancalvitti I think you are having a precedence problem. Is this what you want? `data[All, {Key[b] -> (Framed[#] &)}] // Normal`

Comment: @alancalvitti I don't understand. StringDrop[#,-1]& is a pure function with a single argument.

Comment: @Rojo, thank you, that works. This precedence constraint isn't obvious to me, yet doesn't seem to be documented.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon, I mean that unlike Framed, which is a single argument function and can be passed as both Framed and Framed[#]&, how would you pass 2 argumen functions like StringDrop? However, Rojo simply parenthesized the pure function (of any # of arguments). Why isn't that documented?

Comment: @alancalvitti it is just that `a->b&` is grouped as `(a->b)&` instead of `a->(b&)`. It is a matter of precedence of the operators `&` versus `->`. Operator precedence is documented (tutorial/OperatorInputForms). It is easy to check by repeatedly clicking on the expression (or ctrl+.) and seeing how the selection grows. You can also check the precedences with the undocumented `Precedence/@{Function, Rule}` but I don't think it is too useful

Comment: Related to the bug: If `data = Dataset@{<|"a" -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3|>}` then `data[1, Key@"a"] -> 1` but not `data[1,"a"]`; i.e. is that `Key` is needed also a bug?