# Query or MapAt ragged associations or ignoring Missing values

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, missing

Related to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54520/mapat-and-generic-functions-on-associations-and-datasets) question, can functions be mapped to named Keys in ragged lists of Associations?

```
ds = {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"b" -> 3, "c" -> 4|>}
```

This fails:

```
ds // Query[All, {"a" -> f}]
```

> ```
> {<|"a" -> f[1], "b" -> 2|>, Missing["Failed"]}
> ```

As does this:

```
ds // MapAt[f, {All, "a"}]
```

> MapAt::partw: Part `{All,a}` of `{<|a->1,b->2|>,<|b->3,c->4|>}` does not
>   exist.

One strategy might be to normalize the list by inserting `Missing` values using `KeyUnion`

```
ds // KeyUnion // Query[All, {"a" -> f}]
```

> ```
> {<|"a" -> f[1], "b" -> 2,    "c" -> Missing["KeyAbsent", "c"]|>, 
>  <|"a"->     f[Missing["KeyAbsent", "a"]], "b" -> 3, "c" -> 4|>}
> ```

But in this case is there a way to ignore `Missing`? Perhaps using `Position`? I did not see a specific `MissingBehavior` option that works here.

**EDIT**

As pointed out [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119854/801), `FilterRules` works *in some cases* but it's limited.

This is interesting as that's a v6 function intended for use with Options rather than the v10 Associations.

Here is a the operator version:

```
filterRules[expr_][as_Association] := Query[FilterRules[expr, as]][as];
```

Example:

```
{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3|>, <|"b" -> 4, "c" -> 5|>} // 
 Query[All, filterRules@{"a" -> f, "b" -> g, "c" -> h}]
```

> ```
> {<|"a" -> f[1], "b" -> g[2]|>, <|"a" -> f[3]|>, <|"b" -> g[4], "c" -> h[5]|>}
> ```

However, there are some fails when applied to `Associations`. If the Rules don't mention at least one Key in a given Association, it returns an empty Association - this is at odds with the Query[{key-> f}] semantics.

```
Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"b" -> 3, "c" -> 4|>}][All, 
 filterRules@{"a" -> f}]
```

> ```
> {<|"a" -> f[1], "b" -> 2|>, <||>}
> ```

Also, doesn't seem to work on symbolic Keys:

```
Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, False -> 2|>, <|False -> 3, "c" -> 4|>}][All, 
 filterRules@{"a" -> f, Key[False] -> g}]
```

> ```
> {<|"a" -> f[1], False -> 2|>, <||>}
> ```

And - warning - crashes the kernel with composite Keys:

```
Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, {"b1", "b2"} -> 2|>, <|{"b1", "b2"} -> 3, 
     "c" -> 4|>}][All, 
  filterRules@{"a" -> f, Key[{"b1", "b2"}] -> g}] // n
```

Comment: related: [Applying functions to irregularly distributed Keys in Association lists](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83414/5478)

Answer (score 6):

```
ds = {
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, 
   <|"b" -> 3, "c" -> <|"a" -> 1, "g" -> 2|>|>
}
```

Not perfect but I'd probably use it:

```
ds // Query[
  All, 
  Replace[s : KeyValuePattern["a" -> _] :> MapAt[f, s, "a"]]
]
```

> ```
> {
>   <|"a" -> f[1], "b" -> 2|>, 
>   <|"b" -> 3,  "c" -> <|"a" -> 1, "g" -> 2|>|>
> }
> ```

Or

```
... :> <|s, "a" -> f @ s @ "a"|>
```

or

```
Query[
   All, 
   If[KeyExistsQ["a"][#], MapAt[f, "a"][#], #] &
]
```

Answer (score 5):

Rather hackish but perhaps still of use:

```
Quiet@*MapAt[f, "a"] /@ ds /. _MapAt[x_] :> x
```

> ```
> {<|"a" -> f[1], "b" -> 2|>, <|"b" -> 3, "c" -> 4|>}
> ```

---

Responding to your update something like this might work:

```
filterRules[expr_][as_Association] := 
  as // Query[
     FilterRules[expr, Join[#, Key /@ #] & @ Keys @ as]
       // Replace[{} -> Identity]
   ]
```